# QT: How to create a simple QProgressDialog object

Tags: c++, qt, qgis

I want to add a simple `QProgressDialog` progress dialog to a function called `QgsOgrProvider::extent()` in [qgsogrprovider.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/providers/ogr/qgsogrprovider.cpp) of the QGIS project that can have longer calculation times.

When I tried to get this progress dialog widget on display by adding
`#include <QProgressDialog>` to the includes and

```
QProgressDialog progress(tr("Calculating extent.."), QString(), 0, 100);
progress.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
progress.setValue(30);
progress.setWindowTitle( tr( "Progress Indication" ) );
progress.setAutoClose( true );
progress.setMinimumDuration( 0 );
progress.setLabelText("Labeltext");
```

to the function it compiles and links without any problem but when executing the code I only get a black box at the moment when the progress dialog should be shown.
[image]

According to the QT [QDialog description](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#details) and [QObject description](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#details) I understand that no parent widget necessarily needs to be provided but it would be better to do so as the widget will be positioned in the center to the parent and also it will be destroyed automatically after having finished.
In other examples of the QGIS project I have noticed that either a `parent` is passed, a `nullptr` or a `this` object.
Why does it not work with a `nullptr` and how do I find a parent or create a parent that can be passed to the function if necessary?

Comment: Just opening a dialog is not enough. You have to feed progress values in as well, and you have to do it periodically. Furthermore, you must ensure that paint events are processed when you fed in a new value. (Otherwise, you may get what you got.) There is an example in the Qt doc.: [Find Files Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-findfiles-example.html) (Scroll down or search for `progressDialog.setValue`.) Please, note the call of `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` after `progressDialog.setValue` in that sample which is intended to process the queued paint events.

Comment: Btw. Whether or not you provided a parent widget doesn't have anything to do with this (I strongly believe).

Comment: Thanks for the hings. I know I need to feed the current progress state continuously if I want to see a progress but that's not the point. Shouldn't the widget be displayed anyways?
I tried adding a second `progressDialog.setValue` and also with `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` but the widget keeps staying black.

Comment: Where and how have you defined `progress`? If it is a local variable in a function it won't work. It also won't work if your function does not end. The GUI is only updated when the code returns to the message loop.

Comment: I haven't defined the variable `progress`. I just followed the example code of https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressdialog.html#details. I expect the function always to end, so no cancel button required. How do I get my code to return to the message loop then as you say?

Comment: What I mean is in event driven programming the GUI will not update when you are in a loop or executing any of your functions. Your function must end before an update happens. There is a workaround `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` but that must be called every time you want the GUI to update and probably even more than that because it only processes a portion of the events in the queue at a time.

Comment: That can't be it. Right after `progress.setMinimumDuration( 0 );` I am doing a     `QApplication::processEvents();  progress.setValue(50);  progress.setLabelText("Labeltext"); QApplication::processEvents();` and nothing changes. Having a look at the find files example the only real difference is the `this` pointer to the parent.

Comment: My advice to you is to create a [mcve] that does not include any `QGIS` code at all. Just a 50 line program and test and make sure that you can get the progress to work. As a professional developer I create many such small example projects to test and develop before applying the code to my typical 50K to 200K line programs that I work on in the day job.

Comment: This github user has a lot of examples that I had used in the past to help me learn: [https://github.com/daviddoria/QtExamples](https://github.com/daviddoria/QtExamples) with that said I just looked at the Progress Dialog and it does the same as your code. I am not sure it's correct but I have not tested that example in a long time.

Comment: I see that the documentation for [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressdialog.html#value-prop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressdialog.html#value-prop) says it calls `QApplication::processEvents()` for you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found everything out. These are my findings:

- `QProgressDialog` can be used without a parent
- The black widget is filled with content only when `progress.setMinimumDuration( 0 )` is followed by a `progress.setValue(...)` call followed by a `QApplication::processEvents()` call. This is probably because only  the `progress.setValue()` triggers the widget to be prepared for the output and the `QApplication::processEvents()` then triggers the final output:

```
    progress.setMinimumDuration( 0 );
    progress.setValue(...);
    QApplication::processEvents();
```

- To use the `QProgressDialog` with the QGIS main window as parent the widget objectName "QgisApp" can be accessed via `qApp->topLevelWidgets()`  (example taken from `QgsGml::getFeatures()`)

  ```
  //find out if there is a QGIS main window. If yes, display a progress dialog
  QProgressDialog *progressDialog = nullptr;
  QWidget *mainWindow = nullptr;
  const QWidgetList topLevelWidgets = qApp->topLevelWidgets();
  for ( QWidgetList::const_iterator it = topLevelWidgets.constBegin(); it != topLevelWidgets.constEnd(); ++it )
  {
    if ( ( *it )->objectName() == QLatin1String( "QgisApp" ) )
    {
      mainWindow = *it;
      break;
    }
  }
  if ( mainWindow )
  {
    progressDialog = new QProgressDialog( ... );
    ...
  }
  ```

**UPDATE**:

- A progress bar keeps black if an initial min value is set again, e.g.

```cpp
    progressDialog = new QProgressDialog("Calculating .."), "Abort", 0, max);
    progress.setValue(0);
    QApplication::processEvents();
```

- `progressDialog->show()` raises the window even if a minimum duration is set via `progressDialog->setMinimumDuration( 2000 )` but the window stays **black**
- after the minimumDuration time the progress value must be set in order the progress window to appear
- when `QApplication::processEvents()` is called before a value is set the window appears **black**
- A `progressDialog->setValue(...)` is shown **black** until followed by  `QApplication::processEvents()`